# Listview not populating when using back arrow after typing in search bar

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have a list view with a search bar, i can search a item in the listview and click on the item and navigate to details of that item, but when i click the back arrow i get an System.NullReferenceException on my HttpResponseMessage.
Could someone please advise me as to what i could be doing wrong.
If the search bar is empty it works fine.

ViewModel

```
    private async Task GetProjects(string email)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        ProjectList = new ObservableCollection<ProjectModel>();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://example/api/GetProject/email=" + email + "/"))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {
                            var textresponse = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectModel>>(textresponse);

                            foreach (var t in json)
                            {
                                if (t.pjtIsActive == 1)
                                {
                                    ProjectList.Add(new ProjectModel
                                    {
                                        ..............
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            IsBusy = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
private ICommand _searchCommand;
        public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new Command<string>
                    (async (text) =>
                {
                    if (text.Length >= 1)
                    {
                        ProjectList.Clear();
                        await GetProjects(EmailAddress);
                        var projectSearch = ProjectList.Where(c => c.pjtName.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower()) || c.ClientName.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower()) || c.ContractorName.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower()) || c.pjtNumber.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower())).ToList();

                        ProjectList.Clear();
                        foreach (var item in projectSearch)
                            ProjectList.Add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GetProjects(EmailAddress);
                    }

                }));
            }
        }

private ICommand _projectDetailsCommand;
            public ICommand ProjectDetailsCommand=> _projectDetailsCommand?? (_projectDetailsCommand= new Command(async (object obj) => {
                var item = (obj as ProjectModel);
                ProjectModel project = new ProjectModel();
                ...........
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Project_Details(project));

            }));
```

Content Page

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            BindingContext = new Project_View_ViewModel(Navigation);
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the binding context in the constructor and refresh the required data in the OnAppearing,

```
 private Project_View_ViewModel bindingv;

    public Project_View()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bindingv = new Project_View_ViewModel(Navigation);
            BindingContext = bindingv;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex);
        }
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        try
        {
            if (bindingv != null)
            {
                await bindingv.GetProjects();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, So i have removed the bindingcontext from the OnAppearing() and moved it to the constructor which helps with the crashing, but if i make modifications to the project details and return to the page it doesnt update the view. thats why i had onAppearing() there. I am sorry i forgot to add that piece of info to my question earlier.

Comment: in that case, you need to refresh only the necessary things in the OnAppearing... for example, if you want to refresh the list, change the refresh method to public and call it from onAppearing. I've updated above....

Comment: Thanks Abdul appreciate your help it solved my problem.